# Define Column type in xml file to use as Crystal report data source

Tags: xml, crystal-reports

I use this XML file as data source for my crystal report.

```
<Person>
    <name></Name>
    <Family></Family>
    <BirthDate type="datetime"></BirthDate>
</Person>
```

But when I use this as data source and crystal report engine generates my report columns according to given XML , I see that the BirthDate field is a string. I can not change its type , and I think maybe there is a problem with my XML format

Is there any body to help me?!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late, but I hope this helps those looking for an answer now.
Instead of using a xml, use a xsd. Following your example, it'd be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Person" nillable="true" type="Person" />
  <xs:complexType name="Person">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Family" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="BirthDate" type="xs:dateTime" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Crystal Report will identify the type of the birthdate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the type from the XML, you could use a Crystal formula to convert the "string".

```
If IsDateTime({XML.BirthDate})
    Then CDateTime({XML.BirthDate})
    Else CDateTime(0)
```

*I've never used an XML source in Crystal, so I'm not totally sure how the fields show up in the formula editor. "{XML.BirthDate}" could be in a different format.*

The if/else statement makes it not crash on NULL values (or non-DateTime strings).  They will show up as DateTime 0: "12/30/1899 12:00:00AM"